# Sort Hashmap by Key Alphabetically if Values are Equal

Tags: javascript

I have a string that I convert to a hashmap depending on occurrence of word in string. I then sort the hashmap by values descending. I want to sort the map alphabetically if values are the same.

```
let string = 'This is a test. That is not a test. Test'
string = string.toLowerCase()
let map = new Map()

str = string.replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ");
let x = str.trim().split(" ")

for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if(map.has(x[i])){
        map.set(x[i], map.get(x[i]) + 1)
    }else{
        map.set(x[i], 1)
    }
}
map.delete(undefined)
console.log(map)
let max = 0

const mapSort1 = new Map([...map.entries()].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]))
console.log(mapSort1)
```

The output is

```
  'test' => 3,
  'is' => 2,
  'a' => 2,
  'this' => 1,
  'that' => 1,
  'not' => 1
```

I want it so the keys that have the equal values are sorted alphabetically. Output should be like this:

```
test 3
a 2
is 2
not 1
that 1
this 1
```

Comment: Then say so in your sort callback function: `(a, b) => b[1] == a[1] ? **something here to sort alphabetically** : b[1] - a[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and define a custom compare function to do this.

> **MDN Web Docs:**
>
> ```js
> function compare(a, b) {
>  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
>    return -1;
>  }
>  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
>    return 1;
>  }
>  // a must be equal to b
>  return 0;
> }
> ```

In this case, we can first compare the values of `a` and `b`, then compare their keys if the values are equal.

**Full code:**

```js
let map = new Map([ ["this", 1], ["is", 2], ["b", 2], ["a", 2], ["c", 2], ["test", 3], ["that", 1], ["not", 1], ]);

const mapSort1 = Array.from(map.entries()).sort(
  ([aName, aNumber], [bName, bNumber]) => {
    if (aNumber === bNumber) {
      if (aName < bName) return -1;
      return 1;
    } else if (aNumber > bNumber) return -1;
    return 1;
  }
);

console.log(mapSort1);
```

[Result using `console.log(new Map(mapSort1))`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esv2O.png).